# Android Text over image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I have an imageView with an image, over that image I want to place a text. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Simple way is to take a textView and set it background as you do in ImageView. it will do your work easy..

Comment: just look at below link.
I hope it will help u...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100428/add-text-to-image-in-android-programmatically/26064945#26064945

Answer (score 168):

That is how I did it and it worked exactly as you asked for inside a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/myImageSouce" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/myImageView"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this example. I tried to use the compoundedDrawable textview but there I am not able to set an image url. But it's important to use this workaround in a relative layout for the layout_align settings to be recognized.

Comment: putting the id of control to the alignment solved a lot, thanks

Answer (score 19):

You may want to take if from a diffrent side: It seems easier to have a TextView with a drawable on the background:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        </TextView>
```

Comment: the problem with this answer is you cant control the background attributes like imageView . scale for example .

Comment: creating a drawable can allow you do that I hope @JesusDimrix

Answer (score 7):

You want to use a FrameLayout or a Merge layout to achieve this. Android dev guide has a great example of this here: [Android Layout Tricks #3: Optimize by merging](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html).

Answer (score 7):

You could possibly

- make a new class inherited from the Class ImageView and
- override the Method `onDraw`. Call `super.onDraw()` in that method first and
- then draw some Text you want to display.

if you do it that way, you can use this as a single Layout Component which makes it easier to layout together with other components.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways. You use RelativeLayout or AbsoluteLayout.

With relative, you can have the image align with parent on the left side for example and also have the text align to the parent left too... then you can use margins and padding and gravity on the text view to get it lined where you want over the image.

Comment: I came upon this method by accident.  But it is very handy when you want to put some text over an imagebutton or an imageview.  Example - put the current temperature over the image of the current conditions.

Answer (score 4):

For this you can use only one TextView with `android:drawableLeft/Right/Top/Bottom` to position a Image to the TextView. Furthermore you can use some padding between the TextView and the drawable with `android:drawablePadding=""`

Use it like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textAndImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/yourDrawable"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp" 
    android:text="Look at the drawable below"/>
```

With this you don't need an extra ImageView. It's also possible to use two drawables on more than one side of the TextView.

The only problem you will face by using this, is that the drawable can't be scaled the way of an ImageView.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a TextView and change its background to the image you want to use

Comment: the problem with this answer is you cant control the background attributes like imageView . scale for example .

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code this will help you`

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/gallery1"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#7ad7d7d7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Juneja Art Gallery"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code this will help you

```java
public class TextProperty {
    private int heigt;                              //读入文本的行数
    private String []context = new String[1024];    //存储读入的文本

    /*
     *@parameter wordNum
     *
     */
    public TextProperty(int wordNum ,InputStreamReader in) throws Exception {
        int i=0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String s;
        while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
            if(s.length()>wordNum){
                int k=0;
                while(k+wordNum<=s.length()){
                    context[i++] = s.substring(k, k+wordNum);
                    k=k+wordNum;
                }
                context[i++] = s.substring(k,s.length());
            }
            else{
                context[i++]=s;
            }
        }
        this.heigt = i;
        in.close();
        br.close();
    }


    public int getHeigt() {
        return heigt;
    }

    public String[] getContext() {

        return context;
    }
}
```

````java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;
    private ImageView iv;
    private final int WORDNUM = 35;  //转化成图片时  每行显示的字数
    private final int WIDTH = 450;   //设置图片的宽度

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int x=5,y=10;
                try {
                    TextProperty tp = new TextProperty(WORDNUM, new InputStreamReader(getResources().getAssets().open("1.txt")));
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, 20*tp.getHeigt(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
                    paint.setTextSize(20f);

                    String [] ss = tp.getContext();
                    for(int i=0;i<tp.getHeigt();i++){
                        canvas.drawText(ss[i], x, y, paint);
                        y=y+20;
                    }

                    canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
                    canvas.restore();
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image.png";
                    System.out.println(path);
                    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
                    //Display the image on ImageView.
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}```
````