# Text to Image in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application where I need to generate an Image from text and store that Image to  the SDCard.
Can anyone tell me a library(just like textimagegenerator for java) I need android compatible library or source which I can use for this?

Comment: You could do a capture of the screen, but that depends of what you called text.

Comment: [Please reference the below url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38365013/1223827)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TextView textView = new TextView(activity.getContext());
textView.setText("Hello World");
textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
textView.destroyDrawingCache();
textView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = getTransparentBitmapCopy(textView.getDrawingCache());


private Bitmap getTransparentBitmapCopy(Bitmap source)
{
    int width =  source.getWidth();
    int height = source.getHeight();
    Bitmap copy = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    source.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    copy.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: source is coming as NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`android.graphics.Canvas.drawText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText) for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this

Got the controls.

```
Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String msg=ed1.getText().toString();
```

Create the bitmap, canvas, paint,and invoke drawText function:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 400, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);// 若设置为center，则文本左半部分显示不全 paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);// 消除锯齿
paint.setTextSize(20);

canvas.drawText(msg, 20, 30, paint) ;
canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.restore();
```

Save the image

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/abc.png";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: It would be an issue for a sentence long enough to be within device screen - it would exceed screen on left or right. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Yo can have a look at [this "Android save view to jpg or png" post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png):

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a text view or an image view, you will do this:

```
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    Bitmap bp;
    bp = loadBitmapFromView(tv);

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bp);

try {
    OutputStream fOut = null;
    String path = "/sdcard/";
    File file = new File(path, "imagename here.jpg");
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

    getImageBitmap(bp).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
    fOut.flush();    
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

be sure to put this in your androidmanifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```