# post image in Instagram

Tags: android, instagram

**Question :** In my app I need to post image in Instagram just like FB or Twitter.

**What I have already done** : Login and fetched photographs from the Instagram to my own app. But not getting any way for image posting in Instagram.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yet it is not possible to post image in Instagram like FB or twitter.

But this is another way to achieve this using already installed Instagram and if not this will notify user to download app .

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
        if (intent != null)
        {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
            try {
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imagePath, "I am Happy", "Share happy !")));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

            startActivity(shareIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            // bring user to the market to download the app.
            // or let them choose an app?
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+"com.instagram.android"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please tell me how to add text with image?

Comment: @DennySharma you can add caption in your image and then post , see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100428/add-text-to-image-in-android-programmatically

Comment: So is there any callback method to get the posted photo url from instagram intent ? like startactivityforresult()
P.S : I'm currently banned from asking question on stackoverflow, just because i delete several questions. Sorry for asking in here.

Comment: For those who wanna add caption to the image they can do it by adding this line before starting the activity:
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," the caption");

Comment: does this work fully automatic in background or does it only start the app? I need multiple photo upload.

Comment: @zoidbergi this only starts the app

Comment: Can I send to Instagram intent url (my image stored on server) ?
when I try it Instagram app crashes.

Comment: hi @Akhilesh thanks for your answer its working fine its redirecting to crop screen right but my requirement is to redirect to the instagram EDIT. is it possible?

Comment: @user512 I think no, you have to select manually once you reached Instagram.

Answer (score 13):

No, you can't. Quoted from [Instagram API docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) :

At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:

1. Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app. However, in the future we may give whitelist access to individual apps on a case by case basis.
2. We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

---

**UPDATE:** However, if you're working on iOS (though you tagged Android), there is a way to "send" a photo (in fact, it opens the image in Instagram) via Custom URL Scheme. See [this](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/).

Comment: can we achieve it through using Instagram installed in our mobile ?

Comment: Instagram, the Android app, is a share target on Android, too, so you can pass it images from any app using the standard SEND intent method.

Comment: How www.autogrammer.com is doing this ?

Comment: how to post a comment using instagram api?

Comment: @Nancythakkar you should create a new question to ask, but here is the a short answer: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/

Answer (score 0):

Try this link :

You can use this class to upload image to instagram.

`import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class InstagramPostHelper {

    private static InstagramPostHelper instance = null;

    protected InstagramPostHelper() {}

    public static InstagramPostHelper getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new InstagramPostHelper();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private String GenerateSignature(String value, String key) 
    {
        String result = null;
        try {
            byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes();
            SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256");
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            mac.init(signingKey);
            byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            byte[] hexBytes = new Hex().encode(rawHmac);
            result = new String(hexBytes, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
        return result;

    }

    private static final String COOKIES_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";
    public static java.net.CookieManager msCookieManager = new java.net.CookieManager();
    private HttpsURLConnection conn;

    private static String TextUtilsJoin(CharSequence delimiter, List<HttpCookie> list) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            boolean firstTime = true;
            for (Object token: list) {

                if (token.toString().trim().length()<1) continue;

                if (firstTime) {
                    firstTime = false;
                } else {
                    sb.append(delimiter + " ");
                }

                sb.append(token);

            }
            return sb.toString();
        }


    private String GetJSONStringAndPostData(String jsonaddress,String postdata,String agent)
    {
        String sonuc = "";
        try {

            byte[] postDataBytes = postdata.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");


            URL url = new URL(jsonaddress);


            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", agent);

            //Set Cookies
            if(msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0)
            {
              conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", TextUtilsJoin(";",  msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));    
            }

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            //Get Cookies
            Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = conn.getHeaderFields();
            List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get(COOKIES_HEADER);
            if(cookiesHeader != null)
            {
                for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) 
                {
                  msCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null,HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
                }               
            }



            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));
            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sonuc += output;
            }
            conn.disconnect();
          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return "";
          } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
          }
        return sonuc;
    }

    public void SendImage(String Caption,byte[] ImageByteArray) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, ParseException
    {
        String Agent = "Instagram 6.21.2 Android (19/4.4.2; 480dpi; 1152x1920; Meizu; MX4; mx4; mt6595; en_US)";
        String Guid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String DeviceId = "android-" + Guid;
        String Data = "{\"device_id\":\""  +  DeviceId + "\",\"guid\":\"" + Guid + "\",\"username\":\"MYUSERNAME\",\"password\":\"MYPASSWORD\",\"Content-Type\":\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\"}"; 
        String Sig = GenerateSignature(Data, "25eace5393646842f0d0c3fb2ac7d3cfa15c052436ee86b5406a8433f54d24a5");
        Data  = "signed_body=" + Sig + "." +  URLEncoder.encode(Data, "UTF-8") + "&ig_sig_key_version=4";

        if (msCookieManager.getCookieStore()!= null)
        {
            msCookieManager.getCookieStore().removeAll();
        }
        //Login Request
        String login = GetJSONStringAndPostData("https://instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/", Data,Agent);

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(login);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        if (((String) jsonObject.get("status")).equals("ok")) //Login SuccessFul
        {
            //Login Successful
            System.out.println("Login Successful !");

           //Post Image
            String upload = "";

            try {
                final HttpMultipartHelper http = new HttpMultipartHelper(new URL("https://instagram.com/api/v1/media/upload/"));
                http.addFormField("device_timestamp", Long.toString((new Date()).getTime()));
                http.addFilePart("photo", ImageByteArray);
                final byte[] bytes = http.finish();
                upload = new String(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            System.out.println(upload);
            obj = parser.parse(upload);
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            if (((String) jsonObject.get("status")).equals("ok")) //Login SuccessFul
            {
                String mediaID = (String) jsonObject.get("media_id");

                Data = "{\"device_id\":\"" + DeviceId + "\",\"guid\":\"" + Guid + "\",\"media_id\":\"" + mediaID + "\",\"caption\":\"" + Caption + "\",\"device_timestamp\":\"" + Long.toString((new Date()).getTime()).substring(0,10) + "\",\"source_type\":\"5\",\"filter_type\":\"0\",\"extra\":\"{}\",\"Content-Type\":\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\"}";
                Sig = GenerateSignature(Data, "25eace5393646842f0d0c3fb2ac7d3cfa15c052436ee86b5406a8433f54d24a5");

                Data  = "signed_body=" + Sig + "." +  URLEncoder.encode(Data, "UTF-8") + "&ig_sig_key_version=6";

                //Login Request
                System.out.println(Data);
                String result = GetJSONStringAndPostData("https://instagram.com/api/v1/media/configure/", Data,Agent);

                System.out.println(result);
            }


        }
        else //Login UnsuccessFul
        {
            System.out.println("Login Unsuccessful !" + login);
        }


    }

}`

https://gist.github.com/ecdundar/d5b6bdcc2035448fc9cd

Answer (score 0):

It seems we're now able to do it, for more you can check [official docs here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/)

Comment: It still using intent to share feed. See this code. Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
public void ShareInsta() {



    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "FolderName");
    File imgFile = new File(dir, "0.png");
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + imgFile));
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<---MY TEXT--->.");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share images..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(SaveAndShareActivity.this, "Please Install Instagram", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```