# How to to upload photos (or pass them )to Instagram via my own android app and Tag it with my own message

Tags: android, location, instagram, instagram-api, caption

I am trying to develop an android app and I want to upload an image to my instagram app and write my own message in caption part or add a location. I did some research about it and find I could not use instagtam's API to uploud an image directly. So I am trying to pass my picture to the instagram app and add my caption and location. How can I pass caption message and my location to instagram app?!

Would you please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
    String type = "image/*";
String filename = "/myPhoto.jpg";
String mediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename;

createInstagramIntent(type, mediaPath);

private void createInstagramIntent(String type, String mediaPath){

    // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Set the MIME type
    share.setType(type);

    // Create the URI from the media
    File media = new File(mediaPath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

    // Add the URI to the Intent.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    // Broadcast the Intent.
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
}
```

Comment: thanks my friend, but I need to pass caption message and location to the instagram plus the image , this is my main question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296770/post-image-in-instagram

Comment: What instagram has suggested https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/