# Is it possible to directly share or post photo on instagram from our android app without launching instagram

Tags: android

I want to send photo directly to instagram without launching it. Is it possible?

```
 File file = new File("/mnt/" + path);
         Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                        shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
                        context.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: See if they have a Web service API that you can use.

Comment: This is a duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16296859/7990687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of June 21, 2017, Instagram doesn't have any API or method you can use to post an image to Instagram without opening the app. However, you can find other API endpoints that you can use without opening Instagram from the link below:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/