# How to post image on Instagram not via android Intent?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

After searching on SO and google i found that instagram_basic permission is solution. So i have added product instagram from developer.facebook. Also apply for app review for instagram_basic but facebook rejected and gives me below reason.

"Based on the screencast provided, we are unable to approve your request for the Instagram Graph API. As a result, you will need to upload a new screencast that clearly shows how an end user will login, including the full Facebook login authentication and the steps required to link your Instagram business account(s). Please visit our Examples page to learn more. Your app must also have been reviewed for manage_pages permission. You can apply for manage_pages in the App Review tab."

So now i have applied for manage_pages permission. But still they rejected and gives me below reason.

"Your screencast doesn't show how the use of this permission directly improves the user experience in your app. Unfortunately, we also weren't able to determine this from testing your app manually. All permissions data must be visibly used within your app. We do not accept permission requests for data that you may decide to use later."

[instagram-api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api)
[post-image-in-instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296770/post-image-in-instagram)

I know facebook rejecting because app flow is not clear for facebook. but what i am missing in flow? Please check below screencast of my app flow which i uploaded for app review.
[FacebookAppReviewScreenCast](https://www.facebook.com/100014839483403/videos/576335782871066/)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Facebook App Review ScreenCast is not available

Comment: What error you are getting when open url?       https://www.facebook.com/100014839483403/videos/576335782871066/

Comment: i'm getting : Sorry, this content isn't available at the moment

Comment: Hi, Rahul now you can download my screencast from below url.  http://caperminttechnologies.com/CapermintDesk/dashboard/fileViewer.php?token=pmrfzoym89ky

Comment: OK. i have saw the video. So, when you are adding a story you are actually posting it on Instagram??

Comment: Hi Rahul thanks for reply. Without permission how can i add ? I have tried code from their official doc. but getting error like "You are not authorized user"  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing

Comment: You just can't publish the content without user concern.

Comment: Rahul, From my app i have to write code for post image on instagram, But without facebook permission approval how can i write that code for image upload ? And once user login with fb and instagram we have post content without opening fb/insta app. So is that possible ?

Comment: You can write and test your code by setting app under development mode in https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: @RahulKhurana As per you suggestion we can write code in app development mode, so I am trying to implement content publishing api in graph explorer. Please check my request and response.  Reference:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing      Request:
https://graph.facebook.com/pageid/media?image_url=imageurl.jpg%20&caption=#BronzFonz  , Response: {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (media) on node type (User)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "E0ypbCQol44"
  }
}

Comment: Anyone have idea ? Its bit urgent.

Comment: @RahulKhurana I have tried user/media code from android and graph api explorer as well. But i am getting error: { "error": { "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (media) on node type (User)", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100, "fbtrace_id": "E0ypbCQol44" } }   Is this because facebook close this api for new applicants ?