# how to "paste" some text on a imageview in Android?

Tags: android

I have an android project in which I use the camera and save tho photo in a imageView.
So, I want to paste some text over this imageView. It's possible ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps :

Step 1 : First Change the layout to `RelativeLayout`

Step 2 : Click and drag the **imageview** button inside your workspace and select the image you have stored in your drawable folder.

Step 3 : Choose `TextView` and drag it into your centre of the image. (Rightclick-EditText-Change into ur desired Text).

You can also use **textStyle** or **textSize** to make the text as big and for formatting.

Here is the simple sample code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/sm" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="148dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Here is my text " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Write something like this inside your `RelativeLayout`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/imageSouce" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Or,
Want to do it programmatically?Then follow..

- [Add text to image in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100428/add-text-to-image-in-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` containing your `ImageView` and a `TextView`.  The `TextView` will appear over the `ImageView`.

Comment: I tried to do this but i can't set the position of textview over the imageview

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextView` and set the image background to the text view.

or

If you want to use image view then create `TextView` and place both `TextView` & `ImageView` in a `RelativeLayout`.