# Capture entire content of EditText into a picture

Tags: android, image, android-edittext, capture

I have to print the entire text of a text field into a picture. The reason is: I have to exchange messages with unsupported UTF-8 characters between Android and other web clients. By unsupported UTF-8 characters I mean missing fonts in Android (see [this topic here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aMultilingual_support_for_Android) ). I tried to use the direct way

```
Bitmap b;
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.buildDrawingCache();
b = editText.getDrawingCache();
editText.destroyDrawingCache();
```

which works like a charm until I have multiple lines: The solution captures only the text which is visible to the user instead of the complete text inside of a long text field (scrollbars!).

I also tried another workaround by [generating a picture from a stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11100582/598802). This prints the entire text but does not respect text formatting like newlines. But I don't want to handle all the stuff by myself.

I am forced to use Android 4.3 and earlier versions.

1. Is there smart way to capture text into pictures? If not:
2. Is it possible to modify the code above to get it work as expected?

Comment: What do you mean by "unsupported UTF-8 characters"? It may be simpler for you to convert the `EditText` contents into HTML that the other Web clients can consume, perhaps using logic forked from `Html.toHtml()`.

Comment: I changed my question to clarify the "unsupported UTF-8 characters" question. Eventually I found a free font to workaround this issue. I can only transport text or pictures from my side. But the client on the other side (simple HTML-Browser) does not necessarily have the font which cannot be installed from my side. So I am still facing the export issue. So I decided to transport the text as a picture, which is IMHO the most simple solution to deal with issue.

Comment: Saying you want to send a picture to a third party is fine. Generating that picture via an `EditText` is unlikely to work well.

Comment: As I wrote, generating a picture of EditText is working perfect for the viewable area of the EditText. But if I understand you right you propose me to deal with solution 2 formatting the text by myself?

Comment: I am not sure what "formatting the text by myself" means. I am simply saying that your current approach is unlikely to work well. I would look at the Android 4.4 printing framework and how it generates PDF files and see if you get any ideas of how to create your images using similar techniques.

Comment: I did not say to *use* it. I said to *look at it*, to *get any ideas* for how to solve your problem in other ways. You can tell that by actually reading the comment.

Comment: First, read my question again! I already wrote why I am forced to do formatting by myself if I use solution 2. I am not able to use Android 4.4 (which can be used by very small population of mobile devices currently). I am forced to deal with 4.3 or earlier versions. Pictures are superior to PDF because the latter is not viewable on all devices. Telling me "read it to get an idea" is not helpful because I ask the question having no idea how to deal with the problem. You did not read my question carefully and give no helpful comments. If this is all you can do: Please go out of the line!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for another 24 hours for a solution I ran [into this solution for a Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20963109/598802). The trick is

1. generate another View to hold the content to avoid the marker for EditText on the lower edge of view which will be also printed into the picture
2. copy the Bitmap to avoid problems with software renderer after destroyDrawingCache() when trying to use Bitmap.compress().

Here is the code:

```java
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
TextView textView = new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());

textView.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface());
textView.setText(editText.getText());
textView.measure(
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
textView.layout(0, 0, textView.getMeasuredWidth(), textView.getMeasuredHeight());
textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
textView.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap b = textView.getDrawingCache().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
textView.destroyDrawingCache();

try{
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/picture.png";
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```