# Display TextView over ImageView in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, imageview

I want to display a text over an Image View. I do it like Alesqui suggested here:
[Android Text over image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242951/android-text-over-image)

The preview in Android studio looks fine:
[image: android Studio preview of the xml]

But my actual result looks like this with the text unwantedly above:

[image: Code in Emulator]

I have to add the following XML dynamically to a LinearLayout during the execution:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/myImageSouce" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I add it the following way:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_story_covers);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for (int i = 0; i < stories.size(); i++)
    {
        // add  imageView
        RelativeLayout coverLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cover, null);
        ImageView imageView =(ImageView) coverLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCover);
        TextView textView = (TextView) coverLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewCover);
        textView.setText(stories.get(i).title);
        imageLoader.displayImage(stories.get(i).cover.fileUrl, imageView);
        ll.addView(coverLayout);
    }
```

This must have something to do with that parent LinearLayout. What is the proper way to do get the result?

Comment: the textcolor is wrong. it should be black, not yellow. And it should say Hello, not My Text.

Comment: yeah, it's inconsistent. But i neglected that due to its lesser importance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/myImageSouce" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There are many thing that this answer doesn't provide and you should stop doing. I had an answer as well trying to point them out. It shouldn't have been chosen as the correct one. If anyone has more improvement for my answer, please comment it.

Comment: I also would prefer FrameLayout here, but I don't know the full context of his app and it could be that he wants to do other things that require a RelativeLayout (perhaps he will add more views?), so I intentionally offered only the change that solves his immediate problem.

Answer (score 2):

Tips:

- [Romain guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy) said: "I didn’t say don’t use RelativeLayout, you just must be aware of its (possible) impact on performance if used at the top of the tree." Much better to use a simple FrameLayout if you can.
- Be aware of the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) property in ImageView's
- If you want the ImageView to be the same size as the parent then you need to set it as match_parent height and width. If you use wrap content it will depend on the size of the bitmap and the resolution.
- Consider using match_parent instead of the [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT)  fill_parent
- I would prefer [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for bitmaps management.

-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/myImageSouce"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:text="Test"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: based on this https://www.infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/top-5-android-libraries-every-android-developer-should-know-about I chose UIL. [Also interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995007/local-image-caching-solution-for-android-square-picasso-vs-universal-image-load)

Comment: Well, I should modify my answer and say that Picasso is just my personal preference.