# How to set setbackground image in android using s3 image url

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I have to set Background image of TextView programatically using s3 image url , how to do it ,
I am able to access that image in browser using s3 url 
http://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-824932500732.s3.amazonaws.com/Images/android-icon-36x36new.png .

Comment: Download the image data and then create `Drawable` from the data and set   it to `TextView` using `setBackground(Drawable drawable)`

Comment: But why can't you use `TextView` over `ImageVew`. You can use `FrameLayout` to achieve that

Comment: I am programatically accessing the s3 url of image from database and using that url I have to set background image of TextView because there is large number of images on s3

Comment: I can change it from TextView to ImageView  no problem.. if you have any example then please share link .

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26976190/2809326 thread. Anyway you have to download the image first.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `TextView` (or any View Background) background using [Glide Library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) .

```
Glide.with(this).load(imageURL).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() { 
@Override 
public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resource);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        yourTextView.setBackground(drawable);
    } 
} 
});
```

> Glide will get the Image as Bitmap from URL and convert into drawable and use that drawable for background.

Comment: Glide not able to find ... will I have to add some dependecies

Comment: Yes `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'`. Glide is an image loading and caching library .