# Android CardView containing ImageView and TextView issue

Tags: android, textview, imageview, overlay, cardview

I made an item XML file that I want to pass to an `Adapter` so I can display a list of items within a RecyclerView.

The layout file consists of a `CardView` which contains an `ImageView` to show a movie poster and a `TextView` to display the movie title.

My problem is that I can't find a way to place the `TextView` over the `ImageView` so the title can be seen above the poster.

my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimension_value_10"
>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimension_value_5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/dimension_value_15"
        android:id="@+id/movie_poster_card"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/movie_poster_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movie_title_text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/movie_poster_card"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimension_value_10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimension_value_10"
                android:text="Movie title here"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textSize="26sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

---

Here is the design image to be more explicit:

[image]

Comment: Use a relative layout inside cardview and put imageview and textview inside relative layout.

Comment: [ This may Solve your problem...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976135/display-textview-over-imageview-in-android)

Comment: [ This may Solve your problem...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976135/display-textview-over-imageview-in-android)

Comment: yea this solved it.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **Vertical LinearLayout** inside the **CardView** and center the textView..

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimension_value_5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:elevation="@dimen/dimension_value_15"
    android:id="@+id/movie_poster_card"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/movie_poster_card"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimension_value_10"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimension_value_10"
            android:text="Movie title here"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/movie_poster_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:elevation="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `CardView` is really only meant to have a single child. You should wrap your `ImageView` and `TextView` in something like a `FrameLayout` and make that the `CardView` child.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap imageview and textview in a relative layout and move the elevation to the relative layout container to maintain the shadow effect you're looking for.

Edit::

I'm not sure why this was down voted, since it's the correct answer.

For clarity you should change your code to:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimension_value_5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:elevation="@dimen/dimension_value_15"
    android:id="@+id/movie_poster_card"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/movie_poster_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/movie_poster_card"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimension_value_10"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimension_value_10"
            android:text="Movie title here"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="26sp" />
      </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```